# PHP mcrypt not compiled properly

Tags: php, laravel, lamp, mcrypt

I have tried everything but I not able to fix this error. I installed PHP by downloading it and then ran:

```
brew install php55-mcrypt
```

I had initially installed it with PHP 5.3 then Laravel complained that it has to be greater than 5.4. So everything got messed up.

I am on MAC 10.7. Can someone help me?

```
php -v

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mcrypt: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.5.1 (cli) (built: Aug 14 2013 10:31:02) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: This doesn't go to solve your immediate issue, but consider using Vagrant or another VM-based solution so you don't have to go through this type of stuff on your Macintosh. It's very non-standard Posix-ish setup causes all sorts of trouble :D http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/vagrant-what-why-and-how/

Comment: no one can answer this?

Answer (score 14):

`brew reinstall mcrypt --build-from-source php56-mcrypt --build-from-source`

Build from source is an option which will force brew to compile from source rather than using a bottle.

Comment: Error: No available formula with the name "php56-mcrypt"

Answer (score 0):

Since you had a previous installation of PHP (5.3), and now you just installed a newer version (5.5.1), maybe the new PHP installation are pointing to some old locations.

Look for any `php.ini` you're using, and verify the `extension_dir` directive.

The last suggestion would be to reinstall PHP 5.5.1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .. But I have updated the extention_dir entry in the php.ini .. but did not change anything .. still getting the error ..

Comment: Also I have reinstalled PHP 5.5 but no progress .. :(

Comment: Strange... Seems like I can't be of help.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because of mismatch between php-mcrypt module version and php version in the server. I am not that familiar with brew as I am a Macports user however depending on your unix ditro you can do something like:

=======

```
yum list installed | grep php55
```

=======

```
Sample output:
=======
php55-gd.x86_64                        5.2.14-2.el5.art                   installed
php55-imap.x86_64                      5.2.14-2.el5.art                  installed
php55-mbstring.x86_64                  5.2.14-2.el5.art                installed
**php55-mcrypt.x86_64                    5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1        installed**
php55-mysql.x86_64                     5.2.14-2.el5.art                  installed
=======
```

We can see the php-mcrypt module associated with earlier version of PHP.

How to fix the error?

Update php-mcrypt module to fix the error.

======

```
yum update php-mcrypt
```

======

hope that helps

Comment: He uses MAC OS X and not RHEL/Fedora, so using yum would really help

Comment: oups, it should obviously be wouldn't.